# Roblox In-Game Ban System

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to make an in-game system for banning players. I have a button that fires a remote event with a player's name and a message for why they were banned. But every time I hit the button, I get this error :

`ServerScriptService.Event_Handler:21: attempt to call a nil value`

I have no idea why this is not working can someone help me understand what's going wrong?

**EVENT_HANDLER**

```
local dss = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local bands = dss:GetDataStore("banDataStore")

BanPlayer.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, playertoban, reason)
    local pui = player.UserId
    local success, errormessage = pcall(function()
        bands:SetAsync("Banned-", pui, true)
    end)
    
    if success then
        print("Player Successfuly Banned")
    end
    game.Players:FindFirstChild(playertoban):Kick(reason)
end)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are searching for players by name, it's possible that you could be spelling the name wrong. In that case, `game.Players:FindFirstChild()` will return `nil`. You can sanitize this call by making sure that the player exists before calling `Kick()`

Also, as a side note, it looks like you are banning the player that calls the `BanPlayer` RemoteEvent, not the one whose name is stored in `playertoban`.

```
local dss = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local bands = dss:GetDataStore("banDataStore")

BanPlayer.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, playertoban, reason)
    -- check that playertoban is a real player's name
    local bannedPlayer = game.Players:FindFirstChild(playertoban)
    if not bannedPlayer then
        warn("Could not find a player named " .. playertoban)
        return
    end

    -- record their user-id so we can ban them when they rejoin
    local pui = bannedPlayer.UserId
    local success, errormessage = pcall(function()
        bands:SetAsync("Banned-", pui, true)
    end)
    if success then
        print(playertoban .. " Successfully Banned")
    else
        warn(string.format("Failed to ban %s permanently with error : %s", playertoban, errormessage))
    end

    -- remove them from the game
    bannedPlayer:Kick(reason)
end)
```